# JpGraph Piechart Background Color

Tags: php, colors, jpgraph

I use JpGraph in PHP. I can set background colors for most every chart with

`$graph->SetBackgroundGradient($bgcolor, $bgcolor, GRAD_HOR, BGRAD_MARGIN);`

But how can I set a background color for pie chart?

It's the *Most powerful PHP-driven charts* but there is still no `$graph->SetBackgroundColor($bgcolor)` function.

Br

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at `SetMarginColor()` or `SetColor()`?

http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/Graph.html#_GRAPH_SETMARGINCOLOR

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_pie.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_pie3d.php');

// Some data
$data = array(
    array(80,18,15,17),
    array(35,28,6,34),
    array(10,28,10,5),
    array(22,22,10,17));

$piepos = array(0.2,0.4,0.65,0.28,0.25,0.75,0.8,0.75);
$titles = array('USA','Sweden','South America','Australia');

$n = count($piepos)/2;

// A new graph
$graph = new PieGraph(550,400,'auto');

// Specify margins since we put the image in the plot area
$graph->SetMargin(1,1,40,1);
$graph->SetMarginColor('navy');
$graph->SetShadow(false);

// Setup background
$graph->SetBackgroundImage('worldmap1.jpg',BGIMG_FILLPLOT);

// Setup title
$graph->title->Set("Pie plots with background image");
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,20);
$graph->title->SetColor('white');

$p = array();
// Create the plots
for( $i=0; $i < $n; ++$i ) {
    $d = "data$i";
    $p[] = new PiePlot3D($data[$i]);
}

// Position the four pies
for( $i=0; $i < $n; ++$i ) {
    $p[$i]->SetCenter($piepos[2*$i],$piepos[2*$i+1]);
}

// Set the titles
for( $i=0; $i < $n; ++$i ) {
    $p[$i]->title->Set($titles[$i]);
    $p[$i]->title->SetColor('white');
    $p[$i]->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,12);
}

// Label font and color setup
for( $i=0; $i < $n; ++$i ) {
    $p[$i]->value->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD);
    $p[$i]->value->SetColor('white');
}

// Show the percetages for each slice
for( $i=0; $i < $n; ++$i ) {
    $p[$i]->value->Show();
}

// Label format
for( $i=0; $i < $n; ++$i ) {
    $p[$i]->value->SetFormat("%01.1f%%");
}

// Size of pie in fraction of the width of the graph
for( $i=0; $i < $n; ++$i ) {
    $p[$i]->SetSize(0.15);
}

// Format the border around each slice


for( $i=0; $i < $n; ++$i ) {
    $p[$i]->SetEdge(false);
    $p[$i]->ExplodeSlice(1);
}

// Use one legend for the whole graph
$p[0]->SetLegends(array("May","June","July","Aug"));
$graph->legend->Pos(0.05,0.35);
$graph->legend->SetShadow(false);

for( $i=0; $i < $n; ++$i ) {
    $graph->Add($p[$i]);
}

$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

Reference: http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch16.html